# Sinatra (Ruby) - Posting with Ajax

Tags: jquery, ruby, ajax, sinatra, sequel

I'm attempting to submit some data on the fly to a route using $.post and I am currently faced with a mysterious error that I cannot get my head around.

Here's my route...

```
post "/share" do
    sid   = params[:sid]
    user  = (session[:level] == 1) ? params[:user] : session[:user]
    # Database
    require_relative "../../database/db.rb"
    db = DBShare.new
    db.share(sid, user)
end
```

Here's what I get when my $.post request is sent to the route...

```
!! Unexpected error while processing request: undefined method `close' for 1:Fixnum
```

The ajax call returns in the .fail(), but the database call is completed (I use Sequel for the database call which executes a stored procedure) - interestingly it calls the procedure twice on the first call, and only once on subsequent calls.

I thought it might be because my route was not returning a content header - so I added "success" after the db call.

This resulted in the jquery returning in the .success() block, but the database call was not completed.

Here's my jQuery call

```
// Share or unshare
$(document).on('click', '.share-unshare', function(event) {
    if (event.type == 'click') {
        var element     = $(this);
        var text        = $(this).text();
        var sid         = $(this).attr('sid');
        var r = '';

        // Unshared
        if (text == "Unshare") {
            r = confirm("Are you sure you want to unshare this?");
            if (r == false) {
                return false;
            }
            share(sid, element);

        // Shared
        } else {
            r = confirm("Are you sure?");
            if (r != false) {
                share(sid, element);
            }
        }

    }

    function share(sid, element) {
        var user = $('#details').attr('user');
        $.get('/share/', { 'sid' : sid, 'user': user })
            .success(function(data) {
               if (text == "Share") {
                   element.html("Unshare");
               } else {
                   element.html("Share");
               }
            })
            .fail(function() {
               alert("Something went wrong - unable to share / unshare");
            })
            .always();
    }

});
```

Here's the DB call (the procedure works fine through so not concerned with the PL/SQL)

```
    def share(sid, user)
        sql = "
        BEGIN
            pa_share.pr_share_handle(?, ?);
        END;
        "
        ds = $db_app[sql, sid, user]
    end
```

At this stage - I am thoroughly baffled! Does anyone have any ideas what it might be please?

Many thanks

Ash

**UPDATE:**

I managed to fix this issue by adding **ds.insert** after my params were bound in the db call..

```
def share(sid, user)
    sql = "
    BEGIN
        pa_share.pr_share_handle(?, ?);
    END;
    "
    ds = $db_app[sql, sid, user]
    **ds.insert**
end
```

Comment: What's the status code returned to the ajax call? Are the values you're passing through of the correct types? i.e. `1` and not `"1"`

Comment: Hi Iain - thanks, I did check that. I managed to resolve the issue by adding ds.insert to my DB call after the call was prepared.

Comment: Ah, I see now. It was the return value of `share` that was the problem, as it's either returning a Sequel dataset or just `1` for success when [Sinatra is expecting an array or a string at the end of a route](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Return%20Values). I'd add a bit of error checking code to the end of the route, and then [use `halt` with the status](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Halting) to indicate to the jquery caller how it went. It makes it clearer to everyone (developer/Sinatra/jQuery) what the intention and results should be of that code. Glad you got it working!